# Calculating leave accrued on pro-rata basis for multiple employees on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, user-profile

I have made a leave planner using SharePoint designer, that displays leaves accrued, availed and balance. For now I have kept the accrued fixed for all the employees. But, now I want to assign accrued leaves to every employee based on the pro-rata basis, for the rest of the year. Based on the joining date,the pro-rata will be calculated.

Can you guide me how we can do this? Is it possible to manage every employee individually on sharepoint, where I can manually fix their leaves accrued?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much access you have in SharePoint. You could associate their joining date on their User Profile (for example the Anniversary Date field) and then request the date from the current user and perform your calculation. If you don't have access to the User Profile you may put all this data into a separate SharePoint list, one entry for each user, but even in a small organization this would be a huge pain to manage. Plus you run the risk of users being able to see other users values, which may or may not be a GDPR issue (but I am no lawyer).

I think the real question is, just because you can, should you use SharePoint for this at all? It sounds to me like a solution better suited to a relational database rather than SharePoint lists. You can control the data much more effectively that using lists. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Yes of course its a pain to update the details manually in other SharePoint list, but to be honest I have no good understanding of coding and therefore I am limited to the functionality provided by the Sharepoint. Moreover, I do not have access to the database, and my company being small, I doubt even if they have any such database.

Comment: For now, I have tried using another list in Sharepoint and manually entering the joining date and calculating based on that. It worked well for me.

Comment: I would look into adding a custom field to the User Profile. It is an easy way to store and retrieve the data associated with an individual without exposing it to the rest of the company.